# can't get argv to pass to string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm new to C++ programming (haven't done it in 10+ since college.) and I'm trying to write a very basic program to grab a file name that has been passed as an argument.  I'm just not getting how to get the file name.  I'm using VS2012 Exp for Desktop.

Below is my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <xstring>
#include <string>

//using namespace openutils;
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wcout << "customconsole app has "<< argc <<" arguments passed.  second one is:  " << argv[1];
    ofstream me_attach_file;
    wstring newfilename = argv[1] && ".newext";
    me_attach_file.open (".mailexpress");
    me_attach_file << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    me_attach_file.close();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this

```
wstring newfilename = argv[1] && ".newext";
```

with

```
wstring newfilename = argv[1];
newfilename += L".newext";
```

Some languages use `&` for string concatenation.  C++ does not.  In fact, there is NO operator that concatenates string literals and character pointers: `+` as string concatenation is defined by string objects and works only with them.

In addition, string literals have to be prefixed with `L` to use wide characters and be compatible with `wstring`.

Comment: Okay.... yeah, I should have checked the concatenation first... Probably would have figured it out.  Thanks!! That fixes it!!

Comment: `std::wstring(argv[1]) + L".newext"` is what I would use.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Why?  I specifically considered that and chose not to use it.  (It creates an extra temporary.  Or two.)

Comment: +1 to the post. But about temporaries: surely the compiler will optimize it out. In C++11, wouldn't that be a move-construction, since the temporary will get 'moved' into 'newFilename'? Hardly worth being concerned about. Especially since the bottleneck here will be accessing the harddrive for the file anyway.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Your suggestion calls `std::wstring(const wchar_t*)`, then `std::wstring::operator+(const wchar_t*)`.  Optimal.  My suggestion calls `std::wstring(const wchar_t*)`, then `operator+(std::wstring&&,const wchar_t*)`, then theoretically `std::wstring(std::wstring&& str)` twice, but due to RVO only one should be called.  The other cannot be elided. Though your code avoids a _move_, I still prefer having it on one line.

Comment: @MooingDuck: No, mine does not call `operator+`.

Answer (score 3):

**&&** doesn't add two strings together. The **+** operator does.

Also, C++ decides which of the many **operator +** functions to use by the type of the left-hand argument. You have two different types here, a **_TCHAR** string, a string literal (*"this is a string literal"*) which is type **char***, and you want to put it into a wstring.

First, a **_TCHAR** and **char*** aren't the same type, so it should be **L".newext"**.

Second, you can't add two **char***s, because that is adding two pointers, and pointer arithmatic does something different than what you want. So the first argument needs to be coverted to a **wstring** before you start adding things together.

Either:

```
wstring myStr = argv[1];
myStr += L".newext"
```

Or:

```
wstring myStr = wstring(argv[1]) + L".newext" + L"Additional stuff"
```

Answer (score 0):

in the line

```
me_attach_file.open (".mailexpress");
```

you should pass the filename to the object.

```
me_attach_file.open (newfilename);
```

in your version, ofstream will open a file named ".mailexpress" without prefix (which is hidden on unix systems).

Comment: Does `std::ofstream` in Visual C++ 2012 take a `std::wstring` filename?  I didn't think so...

Comment: it doesn't, though I sure wish it did.